# Show all available variations on archive pages with a button linked to WooCommerce single product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

In WooCommerce, I want to show all available variations of a product in shop and archive page as separate products, so that user can see all available color options without going to details page. i have tried a plugin "variation as single product", but the issue is when converted to single product the select option became add to cart button. I don't want that. I want to show select option and swatches in each separate product also.

I tried different plugins, but unfortunately in all plugins when split the product, the select option button become add to cart. I don't want that.

Comment: In other words you want to show same product X times on shop ? Copy the template content-product.php in your theme. Check if current product is variation and loop and output the data you want. And the plugins works as intended. If i am visitor and lwant to purchase the black tshirt and again from main product forcing me to select the variation is kinda annoying. This is why you have add to cart bcs you skip this part.

Comment: @Snuffy the idea is to show all available product colors without going to detail. as of now if no default attribute is selected, it shows the first available attribute combination. in my case for a product I have size and color attribute. and in shop page I just want to show different products based on color only and customer can click on any product and which lead him to parent product detail page. from there he can choose size also and checkout.

Comment: @Snuffy when looping through the result as you said the issue facing is its showing all product with combination of color and size and only default image is showing all the time

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When using [Variations as Single Product for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-variations-as-single-product/) plugin, it is very easy to replace, in archives pages, the add to cart button from the displayed product variations with a button linked to the single parent variable product:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'variation_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 3 );
function variation_loop_add_to_cart_link( $add_to_cart, $product, $args ) {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_type('variation') ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
            esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ),
            esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
            esc_attr( 'button product_type_' . $product->get_type() ),
            isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : '',
            esc_html__( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' )
        );
    }
    return $add_to_cart;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: I have implemented the code and it looks like this https://snipboard.io/Iu3oXv.jpg. the issue is still not sorted out, my parent product's swatch selection https://snipboard.io/S7ChjL.jpg is not visible in the variations shown in the shop page

Comment: It's because you are using some other plugins like variation swatches and you didn't mention which one in your question as there are 20 different… **Nobody can guess things by magic**, so it's your fault, your question is completely unclear, without any provided code… Don't call me again in the comments for help as I will be definitively dead now. My current code works perfectly with *Variations as Single Product for WooCommerce* plugin. **END**

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I mentioned swatches at the end of the first paragraph of my question but didn't mention the plugin used. it's my bad. https://getwooplugins.com/plugins/woocommerce-variation-swatches/ - This is the one I used. if possible could you help me to sort this out? I'm completely exhausted because of this issue on my site.